# jQuery selecting and exclude an element inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get all the next html code and excluding the DIV with ID=fiscal-address-info using jquery. I started using filter method but no lucky.

This is the original snippet code.

```
<div id="fiscal-info" class="content-fields">
    <div class="content-title"><h2>Datos Fiscales</h2></div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div id="fiscal-address-info">
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
<div id="fiscal-info" class="content-fields">
    <div class="content-title"><h2>Datos Fiscales</h2></div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$('#fiscal-info').filter('#fiscal-address-info');
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the filter method and using a `not` selector:

```
$("#fiscal-info").children().filter(":not(#fiscal-address-info)")
```

This return you all the fiscal-info children ,except the excluded one.

Comment: Thx Andrea for the answer. I guess I was not very clear, I tried to get all the same html but excluding the div with this ID=fiscal-address-info

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .not() method or :not() selector

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Code based on your example:

```
$('div#fiscal-info div').not("#fiscal-address-info");
```

Have a look into this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZB2x/1/)

Comment: it didn't work out. It makes sense the element '#fiscal-address-info' is a child?

Comment: @user3154899 I have edited my post. Plz see the edited answer and attached fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "div" ).filter( $( "#fiscal-address-info" ) );
```

Gets all div elements and filters them for id #fiscal-address-info
Hope this helps!

Comment: There's no other way using as Jquery starter selection: $('#fiscal-info') ?

Comment: This return only the div the OP want to exclude!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fiscal-info div').filter(function () {
    return this.id == 'fiscal-address-info'
}).remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GwbgH/)**